# Decrease imePadding() size in Jetpack Compose Material 2

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, padding

I need to add keyboard padding to a button, but the spacing is too much. Any solution on how I can decrease the size so the button stays at the top edge of the keyboard?

[image]

Here's the code:

```
Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            CustomFloatingActionButton(
                text = "",
                icon = { Icon(imageVector = ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.ic_pencil_plus), contentDescription = "") },
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(
                        ScreenItem.ModifyNote.route
                    )
                },
                Modifier.imePadding()
            )
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState
    )
```

I've also added this to AndroidManifest.xml:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Edit 1: CustomFloatingButton contains nothing exceptional, it's just a simple wrapper around FAB.

Edit 2: Using `Compose 1.2.1` and `Material 2`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete and not easy to test.
Anyway you can pass `WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)` to `Scaffold` and then apply `padding(scaffoldPadding).consumeWindowInsets(scaffoldPadding).systemBarsPadding()` internally to the Scaffold.

Something like:

```
Scaffold(
    modifier = Modifier.imePadding(),
    contentWindowInsets = WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0),
    floatingActionButton = {
        ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding(),
            //...
        )
    },
    floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
){

    Box(Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(it).consumeWindowInsets(it).systemBarsPadding()
    ) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 That might be exactly what I required. I knew something was off. I'll test it today and mark your answer if it works.

Comment: There's no "contentWindowInsets" attribute in my Scaffold. Are you using Material 3? Because mine is Material 2.

Comment: Tested again with `Modifier.windowInsetsPadding(WindowInsets(0, 0, 0, 0)` instead of `contrentWindowInsets`, doesn't work.